# Rounding BigDecimal as in mathematics not working

Tags: kotlin, rounding

I need a function that takes `BigDecimal` and rounds it to 2 digits according to math rules, so `10.495 -> 10.50` and `10.494 -> 10.49`

As far as I understand, that's behavior of `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN', so I'm doing this

`BigDecimal(10.495).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`

and the result is `10.49`, which is not correct

but if I create `BigDecimal` using `String`, like this

`BigDecimal("10.495").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`

it rounds it correctly to `10.50`

why is that? and how to accomplish this, so I can have one function
`fun round(value: BigDecimal): BigDecimal`

that takes `BigDecimal` and returns correctly rounded `BigDecimal`?